# why pointer to function type is absent in the list of deducible type

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Test{};  

template<typename Ret, typename...Args>
struct Test<Ret(*)(Args...)>{
    using type = int;
};
void func(int){}
int main(){
  Test<decltype(&func)>::type b;
}
```

If type `P` is `Ret(*)(Args...)` and the corresponding argument type `A` is `void(*)(int)`, the deduction attempt to deduce template argument from `A`, however such form is not listed in the following list which specifies the what form of type can be deduced.

[temp.deduct.type#8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#8)

> A template type argument T, a template template argument TT or a template non-type argument i can be deduced if P and A have one of the following forms:
>
> > - T
> > - cv-list T
> > - T*
> > - T&
> > - T&&
> > - T[integer-constant]
> > - template-name  (where template-name refers to a class template)
> > - type(T)
> > - T()
> > - T(T)
> > - T type::*
> > - type T::*
> > - T T::*
> > - T (type::*)()
> > - type (T::*)()
> > - type (type::*)(T)
> > - type (T::*)(T)
> > - T (type::*)(T)
> > - T (T::*)()
> > - T (T::*)(T)
> > - type[i]
> > - template-name  (where template-name refers to a class template)
> > - TT
> > - TT
> > - TT<>

The list specifies so much however pointer to function type is absent, only function type such as `T(T)`   is comprised, so why a pointer to function type is absent in this list, such type should be deducible.

Comment: Note that temp.deduct.type is a sub-section of temp.fct.spec (_Function template specializations_), whereas your example is not a function template.

Comment: @dfri It doesn't matter. Type deduction is mentioned in many sections. It specifies how to deduce template argument for type `P` from argument type `A`. It's not limited that only can be used in Function template specializations

Answer (score 5):

<s>A pointer-to-function type `Ret(*)(Args...)` is nothing but a `T*` where `T` is `Ret(Args...)`.</s>

Edit: further examination has proven that this is not sufficient.

Comment: You mean that here `P` is a compound type where `T` denote the function type?

Comment: @jackX precisely :)

Comment: However the form of `T*` is not equivalent to that of `Ret(*)(Args...)`? They're the distinction form. How to interpret this. you only can say, for case `struct Test<T*>` can be deduced for `T*` from `void(*)(int)`.

Comment: @jackX hmm, it looks like you're right. There would be no sense in listing both `T (type::*)()` and `T type::*` otherwise. I'm clearly not awake enough to make sense of that pile of rules so I'll just start scratching my head as well.

Comment: You got my meaning.

Comment: Doesn't https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#11 help?

Comment: _«There would be no sense in listing both `T (type::*)()` and `T type::*` otherwise.»_ See [CWG2328](http://wg21.link/cwg2328): «We have special case rules for pointers to member functions, even though they're not a special case and should be covered by the rule for pointers to members and the rule for functions.»

Comment: @LanguageLawyer  The sentence sounds like we can substitute more composition types into `T` within any form that is listed in that list. However that list does not cover a form of type-id that denotes pointer to function types.